# Is it possible to get next sibling using cssContainingText in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor, end-to-end

Is it possible to get the next sibling by using by.cssContainingText()

Example:
HTML code is like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="SomeNgRepeat" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="text-label" >SomeText</div>
    <div class="some-class">SomeValue</div>
</div>
```

Get element by using:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('div.text-label','SomeText'))
```

Now find the next sibling of the above element.

I know of `css=form input.username + input` way of finding the sibling. However, this is not working in my case!

I think 'chaining' can be used to achieve this, but don't know How!

Thanks,
Sakshi

Comment: Need to see the source HTML.

Comment: Edited Question to include Code!

Comment: Did you try the nth-child approach? Just increment the parent div child number to get the next element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What if you would get it in one go using [`by.xpath()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@class="text-label" and . = "SomeText"]/following-sibling::div'))
```

Or, you can combine it with `cssContainingText()`:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('div.text-label','SomeText')).element(by.xpath('following-sibling::div'))
```

Comment: Thanks alot alexce. This worked like magic :) Is there a link which contains all these following-sibling kindof css selectors? If not, then maybe you can list them out here. This will make life a lot easier :)

Comment: @SakshiSingla glad it worked. As for xpath-axes related information, see, for example, [mozilla's developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes).

Comment: I want to add a 'text' search in the below xpath. Is there a possibility?(Since its non-angular, so chaining is not supported here!)
browser.driver.findElements(by.xpath('//*[@id="some-id"]//tr/td[1]'));
Something like:
browser.driver.findElements(by.xpath('//*[@id="some-id"]//tr/td[1][.="sometext"]'));

Comment: browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="someId"]//tr/td[1]/self::td[.="'some_text'"]')) WORKED!!

Comment: Its good in a way :) But anyways, thanks a lot for your responses. Those really help a lot :)

Comment: Is it possible to get an element by substring? Like if an element has text 'I am here'. I want to match only 'here' substring. Something like: by.xpath('span[@id="ID" and .*="here"]')@alecxe: Is it possible to get an element by substring?

Comment: Achieved using the following: by.xpath('//*[@id="ID"] [text()[contains(.," here")]]')

Comment: @SakshiSingla you are solving it by yourself again :) Btw, you can simplify the expression a bit: `//*[@id = "ID" and contains(., " here")]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the node.nextSibling selector. Check out this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling)

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

I have designed a plugin to address this specific issues: [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)

The plugin provides some handly locators to find out siblings in a better way and most importantly with CSS selector.

using this plugin, you can directly use:

```js
var elem = await element(by.cssContainingText('div.text-label','SomeText')).nextSibling();
```

or, use booster as by-locator

```js
var elem = element(by.cssContainingText('div.text-label','SomeText')).element(by.followingSibling('div'));
```

Hope, it will help you...