# How to click on table record by.cssselector with partial text present in code snippet

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have a table with header Task details and TaskTime. Task details column contain some text (Perform Operation roll no. **150**) and onclick there is java script operation is performed and new page is displayed in same window.

I want to click on particular table cell say 2nd or 3rd or any cell using partial text roll no. by using findelementBy.cssselector.

Below is my code snippet for table which gets frequently updates and different roll no. gets added to table

```
<tr class="Pointer" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" title="Perform" style="">
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">Perform Operation roll no. 150</td>
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">07 Jul 2015 05:26 PM</td>


<tr class="Pointer" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" title="Perform" style="">
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">Perform Operation roll no. 161</td>
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">07 Jul 2015 05:18 PM</td>


<tr class="Pointer" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" title="Perform" style="">
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">Perform Operation roll no. 155</td>
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack">07 Jul 2015 05:13 PM</td>
```

Note my xpath is not working properly and below table will frequently changes.

Comment: If you ask me, xpath will easily solve your problem. As you said, you want to click on 2nd or 3rd of any cell using partial text roll number, so do you want locate that element with partial text containing the concerned roll number or any element with partial text containing any 'roll no.' will do ?

Comment: Your question is not clear . What is your xpath which is not working?

Comment: @subh: Yes partial text using roll number will also do. 
As xpath is slow I would prefer to go with CSS with partial text.

Bhupesh: My xpath is working for 1st row but if I want to click on 2nd or 3rd depends on roll no I am not able to make

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(),'roll no. 161')]
```

This will locate the `td` element that has innerHTML/text as `roll no. 161`. You can always replace `161` with any other roll number you want to locate.

### OR

In case you want to click on 2nd, 3rd or any other `td` element with respect to the text **roll no.** on the list, you can try these:

- `(//td[contains(text(),'roll no.')])[2]`

This will locate the **2nd** `td` element in the chronological order of DOM representation that contains innerHTML/text as `roll no.`.

- `(//td[contains(text(),'roll no.')])[3]`

This will locate the **3rd** `td` element in the chronological order of DOM representation that contains innerHTML/text as `roll no.`.

Similarly, you can replace the last `[2]` with any other number to locate the concerned element in the page.

Comment: Locator not found
[error] locator not found: xpath=(//td[contains(text(),'roll no.')])[2]

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. I tried with the same HTML snippet so added in question, at my end; it's working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

After going deep into css I am able to locate element inside selenium ide

```
css=tr.Pointer > td:contains(roll nos)
```

Above roll nos will change frequently so is the element locator.

Comment: Is it working fine with this css ? I don't think **[CSS3 supports locating elements using innerHTML/text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29539901/4193730)**

Comment: Exactly same issue I found when trying in Java webdriver code.
Its working fine in Selenium IDE but `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr.Pointer > td:contains(roll nos)")` gave me InvalidSelectorException. 
In short contains is not supported in CSS3 when used in java code.

Is there other workaround for contains?

Comment: Only way out. Try using the xpaths instead, that I had provided earlier, and let me know what issues are you facing please.